# Multiselect ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, multi-select

I'm having trouble in multiple items selection in an ListBox.

I've tried deriving new control from Selector and writing ListBox helper class which did not work (as expected).

The issue with Selector class is, it does not expose SelectedItems and it's hell to bind the property and manipulate it with selection changed event.

The issue with ListBox Helper class is, I'm getting the required data on multiple selection but it never hits the bound property.

Does anybody know a better way to implement multiselect listbox?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: P.S. Seems, I've provided less info. I'm using MVVM where SelectedItems is not accessible without readonly property binding, which is again an overhead for me. :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) has multiple selection already implemented. Just change [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) property to Multiple or Extened.

You can use [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) property to get all the selected items afterwards.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu But it is not possible to set SelectedItems from the viewmodel?

Comment: @Vitalii Vasylenko Yes you can, but not straight forward. Have a look here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142976/how-to-support-listbox-selecteditems-binding-with-mvvm-in-a-navigable-applicatio